# How to disable "nonPast" validation for a date field if the value is empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

There is a form with two date fields. The first one is required and the other is not required. Both fields have `nonPast` validation:

```
$('#my_form').validate({
    rules: {
        start_date: {
            nonPast: true,
            date: true,
            required: true
        },
        end_date: {
            nonPast: true,
            date: true,
            required: false
        },
    }
});
```

But when a user tries to save a form only with `start_date` field, it gets `Date can't be in the past` for `end_date`. Is there any way to disable `nonPast` validation for a field that is not required if a value of that field was not specified?

Comment: There is no such method called `nonPast` within the jQuery Validate plugin.  If you want help, then you're expected to show us a complete and concise example.  Where is the `nonPast` method and where is your HTML markup for the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"Is there any way to disable nonPast validation for a field that is not required if a value of that field was not specified?"*

If a field is not required, then none of the rules should be evaluated.  In other words, your `nonPast` function contains a flaw in its logic.  You did not show us this function but I can guess at what's likely missing...

Please look at the two examples in [the `addMethod()` documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).  Notice the `this.optional(element)` part?  This is what makes the plugin ignore this rule if/when the field is left empty.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("domain", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^http:\/\/mycorporatedomain.com/.test(value);
}, "Please specify the correct domain for your documents");
```